# Test for destroying associated records when object is destroyed failing in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, railstutorial.org

Im stuck on the test in listing 10.15 of Michael Hartls ruby on rails tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#code-micropost_dependency_test). My user_spec.rb is as follows

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  before { @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar") }

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest) }
  it { should respond_to(:password) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation) }
  it { should respond_to(:remember_token) }
  it { should respond_to(:admin) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }
  it { should respond_to(:microposts) }

  it { should be_valid }
  it { should_not be_admin }

  describe "with admin attribute set to 'true'" do
    before do
      @user.save!
      @user.toggle!(:admin)
    end

    it { should be_admin }
  end

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo. foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        @user.should_not be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    it "should be valid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo.COM A_US-ER@f.b.org first.lst@foo.jp a+b@baz.cn]
      addresses.each do |valid_address|
        @user.email = valid_address
        @user.should be_valid
      end
    end
  end

  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password is not present" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " "}
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password confirmation is nil" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = nil }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email(@user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
      it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }
      it { should_not == user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }
    end
  end

  describe "with a password that's too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
  end

  describe "remember token" do
    before { @user.save }
    its(:remember_token) { should_not be_blank }
  end

  describe "micropost associations" do
    before { @user.save }
    let!(:older_micropost) do
      FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user:@user, created_at: 1.day.ago)
    end
    let!(:newer_micropost) do
      FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user:@user, created_at: 1.hour.ago)
    end

    it "should have the right microposts in the right order" do
      @user.microposts.should == [newer_micropost, older_micropost]
    end

    it "should destroy the associated microposts" do
      microposts = @user.microposts.dup
      @user.destroy
      microposts.should_not be_empty
      microposts.each do |micropost|
        Micropost.find_by_id(micropost.id).should be_nil
      end
    end
  end

end
```

When i run the tests i get the following error :

```
  1) User micropost associations should destroy the associated microposts
     Failure/Error: Micropost.find_by_id(micropost.id).should be_nil
       expected: nil
            got: #<Micropost id: 2, content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: nil, created_at: "2012-12-19 09:49:24", updated_at: "2012-12-19 10:49:24">
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:133:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:132:in `each'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:132:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

In my user.rb i have added the dependent :destroy as follows, which is required for the test to pass.

```
has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
```

Why is the test still failing ?

Thank You

Answer (score 39):

I would encourage you *not* to do something like:

```
expect { @user.destroy }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
```

This only tests the any user was deleted, it does not confirm that the correct records were deleted. Instead, I would do something like this

```
@user.destroy
expect { @user.reload }.to raise_error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
```

This ensures the correct user was deleted.

Comment: This is not recommended as explained by the following: WARNING: Using `expect { }.not_to raise_error(SpecificErrorClass)` risks false positives, since literally any other error would cause the expectation to pass, including those raised by Ruby (e.g. NoMethodError, NameError and ArgumentError), meaning the code you are intending to test may not even get reached.

Comment: @Hamdan what you said doesn't make sense. to test it was destroyed, ^ comment makes sense. to test it was *not* destroyed you could simply test it still exists...

Comment: Or it was edited or Im completely mad indeed lol but as you can see I was telling about .not_to and not to .to. I think it was edited!

Answer (score 11):

Consider testing with a more abbreviated `expect .. to change` test:

```
it "destroys the associated microposts" do
  expect { @user.destroy }.to change(Micropost, :count).by(-2)
end
```

Replace the `-2` with whatever change value you'd expect. For example, if it deletes 1 `Micropost` record, then change it to `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the microposts are not linked to the user, a you can see by `user_id: nil`:

```
Micropost id: 2, content: "Lorem ipsum", user_id: nil, created_at: "2012-12-19 09:49:24", updated_at: "2012-12-19 10:49:24"
```

I believe the `belongs_to: user` association is missing in the Micropost model.